# Capitalizing a name using Liquid, doesn't work with special characters

Tags: templates, html-email, liquid

I've got next to no experience with liquid.

I'm working on email newsletter templates and I've got a liquid array that's outputting the users first name and capitalizing it.
My problem is that this company is Norwegian and we've got some special characters like æ, ø and å. When these are involved the code capitalizes that letter as well: like JØrgen (in stead of Jørgen), is there any way around this?

I've also got a scenario where the user has a double name seperated with a dash; Jan-Thomas, this gets rendered Jan-thomas. Anyway to include this as well in a liquid code?

Greetings {% if user.name.size > 0 %}{{ user.name | split: " " | first | capitalize }}{% else %}traveller{% endif %}.

Answer (score 1):

Since Liquid is a Ruby-based templating language I think it has the same limitation to `capitalize` as Ruby's string class:

> case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-capitalize

Comment: Thanks Erik. Could you help me with the Second part?

Comment: You can use `assign` to save the split string, loop over and capitalize each one, then join the array to put the hyphen back in the middle and print the result. The assign/foreach is demonstrated [here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#sort).